# Как подключить сетевой ip-телефон через vpn?

Tags: ip, маршрутизация, vpn, openvpn

Проблема такая, есть сетевой ip телефон. По идее он просто втыкается в порт роутера и все. Но он настроен на выход с определенного ip адреса, а у роутера адрес динамический. Тут и проблема.

Определенный постоянный ip адрес у меня есть, настроен на компьютере через openvpn клиент через свой настроенный open vpn сервер.

Вопрос как подключить телефон?
Я сначала думал настроить openvpn на роутере, но похоже не поддеживает мой роутер..
Потом подумал подключить телефон в сетевую карту компьютера и разрешить сетевым подключениям выход в интернет через подключение к интернету компьютера (через wifi), но похоже он работает в обход vpn  хотя vpn настроен так что весь трафик заворачивается через openvpn

кстати когда на запущенной виртуалке через браузер проверяю свой ip тоже работает в обход vpn

наверное нужны какие то маршрутизации настройки? или можете еще есть способ?

Comment: *он настроен на выход с определенного ip адреса, а у роутера адрес динамический.* Фраза непонятна от слова "совсем". То, о чём Вы говорите - это два совершенно разных и никак не связанных между собой адреса. Они даже на разных устройствах!

Comment: *Я сначала думал настроить openvpn на роутере, но похоже не поддеживает мой роутер..* Узнайте точно. Если правда не поддерживает - меняйте нафиг роутер.

Comment: Хочу добавить уточнение. Итак, у вас на компе есть OpenVPN - клиент, и вероятно, что то (программный IP-телефон?), который позволяет проверить, что есть соединение с ip-телефонной станцией. Так? И при этом Вы можете настроить IP-телефон как угодно? (например, поменять в нём IP и port подключения

Comment: @S.H. из этой фразы "Потом подумал подключить телефон в сетевую карту компьютера и разрешить" следует, что телефон вполне аппаратный, физический.

Comment: @gbg - я не спорю с тем, что телефон аппаратный. я подумал, что если на компе запустить openvpn подключение, и включить tcp-прокси, то можно через этот tcp proxy подключить аппаратный телефон

Comment: да телефон физический. уже настроенный. менять его конфиг НЕ могу. ибо прислала фирма доступа к веб конфигу нет. мне надо сделать так, чтобы он выходил через мой vpn постоянный ip адрес.

Comment: похоже все оказалось проще. подключил телефон к сетевой карте. он получил ее ip высветился на дисплее, но не регистрируется в сети. а потом в настройках vpn адаптера - разрешил использовать это подключение для сетевой карты... и все заработало) вопрос снят) всем спасибо